# SetText not working in Android Studio using Java

Tags: java, android

I made two timers. At some point one of them is increasing and other one is decreasing. I made two integers to increase/decrease every second and use `setText` for `TextView`. But for some reason it's not updating. I printed out integers and code was working but text isn't changing for `TextView`. Here's my code:

```
TextView timerone, timertwo;
int turn = 1;
int timerOne = 20;
int timerTwo = 20;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin_after);
    timerone = findViewById(R.id.timerone);
    timertwo = findViewById(R.id.timertwo);


    timerone.setText(String.valueOf(timerOne));
    timertwo.setText(String.valueOf(timerTwo));
    Thread counterThread=new Thread(()->{
        try{
            while(true){
                if(turn % 2 == 0) {
                    timerOne++;
                    timerTwo--;
                }else{
                    timerOne--;
                    timerTwo++;
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    });
    counterThread.start();
}
```

Comment: You can only set test on the main ui thread. You can't change the UI on that new thread.

Comment: I tried that but still didn't work

Comment: Show us what you've tried, because that solution is definitely better than the current one you have posted. What I'm telling you is not up for debate. It's the way Android works. You can not call setText from a different thread. Maybe call a Toast instead. A toast every 4 seconds, you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution

```
Thread counterThread=new Thread(()->{
        try{
            while(true){
                if(turn % 2 == 0) {
                    timerOne++;
                    timerTwo--;
                }else{
                    timerOne--;
                    timerTwo++;
                }
                 // Here you will be updating textview's
                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        timerone.setText(String.valueOf(timerOne));
                        timertwo.setText(String.valueOf(timerTwo));
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    });
    counterThread.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to modify views from off the UI thread, you need to use `runOnUiThread` or you will get an error. The following works to update the text views inside the loop.

```java
TextView timerone = findViewById(R.id.timerone);
TextView timertwo = findViewById(R.id.timertwo);

timerone.setText(String.valueOf(timerOne));
timertwo.setText(String.valueOf(timerTwo));

Thread counterThread=new Thread(()->{
    try{
        while(true){
            if(turn % 2 == 0) {
                timerOne++;
                timerTwo--;
            }else{
                timerOne--;
                timerTwo++;
            }
            
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                timerone.setText(String.valueOf(timerOne));
                timertwo.setText(String.valueOf(timerTwo));
            });

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
});

counterThread.start();
```

Note, if your version of Java doesn't support lambdas, you can use this instead

```java
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        timerone.setText(String.valueOf(timerOne));
        timertwo.setText(String.valueOf(timerTwo));
    }
});
```